# SSL test fails with a domain pointing at external server

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

Mmmmm.... I'm not really familiar with all this SSL stuff and struggling with this weird SSL issue now.  Well, there is an godaddy account that has three domain in use.

1.jeounggi.com

2.surgicalsmart.com

3.bitesinstitute.com

Web applications for jeounggi.com and surgicalsmart.com are stored on GoDaddy hosting server and a web application for bitesinstitute.com is stored in a private server running by another web developer.

The problem is, after renewing SSL certificates for all three and running ssl test at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest,  #1 and #2 pass but not #3. I thought it would either succeeed all or fail all...  What might be the issue here? SSL setting? or is it the private server?

(The web developer asked me to send renewed ssl-certificate files tho. He must have done things that should be done from the server side i guess...)

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Like I said, I'm not familar with server stuff... please let me know if there are credential information not to be seen here. I will immediately delete the information.

Comment: To be blunt, neither is your web developer. The reason why that server is not passing the tests is that it's not set up according to best practices. You should forward the results of this test to the developer and ask them to fix it.

Comment: Wow... that's a *lot* of bad fails on that server. That's not just "not set up according to best practices", that's "actively incompetent at running a server on the Internet".  I'd be looking for alternate hosting, and fast.

Comment: Thank you for your advice.  I'm a front-end web application developer and didn't know this was that serious :(

Comment: I've forwared the results of this test to him.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need to download the updated certificate and provide securely to
>   your Web dev to upload to the private server. From your screenshot
>   looks like the the site is running from a self signed certificate.
>   Sorry wrong answer.

Okay I've just seen the full report from qualys. Looks like the cert is uploaded but I would think its a matching issue on the subject alternate names in the cert. ie. In the list of names you have bitesinstitute.com but the canonical name for the site is www.bitesinstitute.com.

Comment: So my renewing ssl is successful but the private server is not up-to-date with all that renewed ssl certificate info? I will try to contact GoDaddy and the developer tmr moring. :)  Thx.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Then why would surgicalsmart.com has passed the test while it also doesn't have www.  Sorry for my silly question.

Comment: I've contacted GoDaddy, confirmed that the ssl version on the private server is not up-to-date, and notified the developer.   Thanks u for your answer, Michael.